# R: Row sums for 1 or more columns

Tags: r, rowsum

This is frustrating as it feels like it should be so simple but it's sucking up hours.

I want to get the row sums for a list of columns in a data frame, but that list - which is set by the user - may very well be length 1 i.e. one column number.

`rowSums` doesn't allow summing 1 column.

`rowsum` uses group which I've found completely indecypherable. I've played with the example for ages and still have no clue quite what it's for, but it can't be omitted.

The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103031/calculate-row-sum-and-product-in-data-frame) uses `rowSums` or `apply`; the second uses `.SD` and `lapply` but uses `:=` and `.SD` and other terms which don't appear in R help, nor have I seen before, which just opens another wormhole of searching and confusion.

So: is there anything I can use for:

```
x <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 5)
goodcols <- c(1,3,5)
y <- rowSums(x[,goodcols])
```

that would work with either 1 or >1 goodcols?

Thanks in advance. Currently i'm looking at using:

```
ifelse(length(goodcols)>1,
y<-rowSums(x[,goodcols]),
y<-x[,goodcols])
```

Comment: just use `drop=FALSE` to avoid x being changed into a vector when there is only one column. `.SD` and `:=` are syntax from package `data.table`. One last thing, put `y <- rowSums(x[,goodcols])` instead of `y <- rowSums[,goodcols]`, that should work better ;-) (so what you need is `y <- rowSums(x[, goodcols, drop=F])`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have only one column left in a `data.frame`, `matrix`, or `array`, R coerces it to a `vector`. To keep the dimensions, you need to use the parameter `drop`.
`Drop` is defined (as you can read in `help("[.data.frame")`) by :

> logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.

So, in your case, you need to use the following code if you want `rowSums` to work whatever the number of columns is:

```
y <- rowSums(x[, goodcols, drop = FALSE])
```