# How do I multiply a range of columns together in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, matrix-multiplication

All I want to do is multiply my numeric columns together to create a new column.

The below example is a simplification in that I'll have far more numeric columns than 2, so can't just do `df$C2 * df$C3`.

Essentially if I have a table that looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','B','C','D'),C2=c(1,2,3,4),C3=c(5,6,7,8))

   C1 C2 C3
1  A  1  5
2  B  2  6
3  C  3  7
4  D  4  8
```

I'd like to return C4 where:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
1  A  1  5  5
2  B  2  6  12
3  C  3  7  21
4  D  4  8  32
```

I'd like to do it in a more dynamic way than writing out each column as I have far more than 2 and they'll continue to change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated please!

Comment: So, if your data.frame has 50 variables (i.e., columns), are you looking for a new column with the product of all 50 variables?

Comment: exactly @rdelrossi!

Comment: Think this has been answered before, so I'll hunt for a duplicate, but in the meantime `Reduce(\`*\`, df[c("C2","C3")])`

Comment: @thelatemail I guess instead of c("C2", "C3") I'd replace it with names(df) and somehow take off the first col? or somehow grab all numeric column headers?

Comment: @Josh - yep, lots of options - `names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]` or `names(df)[-1]` or  `paste0("C", 2:3)` or if there's a pattern something like `startsWith(names(df), "C")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103031/calculate-row-sum-and-product-in-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rowwise` in combination with `c_across`.

And the most important part probably is to specify the columns to select which can be done with different tidy select helpers. Here‘s one option, assuming that all your columns start with C followed by a number:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C4 = prod(c_across(num_range('C', 2:3)))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  C1       C2    C3    C4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     5     5
2 B         2     6    12
3 C         3     7    21
4 D         4     8    32
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'll need, thank you @deschen!

Comment: To make that a little more generic, `mutate(product = prod(c_across(where(is.numeric))))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following if the number of columns are unknown but processing starts from column#2

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(tmp_prod = prod(dplyr::c_across(2:last_col()),na.rm = T))
```

Output:

```
 C1       C2    C3 tmp_prod
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A         1     5        5
2 B         2     6       12
3 C         3     7       21
4 D         4     8       32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c('C2', 'C3')

y <- paste0('df$', x, collapse='*')

df$C4 <- eval(parse(text=y))
```